# Is this code efficient?

Tags: powershell

I have a script to test if servers are up, the script I have works great, Im just wondering if it could be optimized more, or is it great just the way it is? It looks for servers that all begin with a certain prefix, in this case 'PreSvr*' If it finds one of them up and running, it stops processing the rest, and tells me the name of the first one it found. If it finds none of those servers responded, it will tell me so.

```
$found = $null
$status = $false
$SvrName = "PreSvr*"
$GetSvrs = (Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like $SvrName}).Name
foreach ($Svr in $GetSvrs)
{
    try {$Status = (Get-Service -ComputerName $Svr -Name WinRM -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Status} catch {$Status = $false}
    IF ($Status) {$Found = $Svr;break}
}

IF ($Found) {$Svr} Else {"No Server Responded"}
```

Comment: Try [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get status of WinRM service status, if that is the purpose - below code should work. You can break rather inside try block itself.

```
$found = $null
$winRMServiceStatus = $null
$serverReachable = $false
$srvName = "*"
$getSvrs = (Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like $srvName}).Name
foreach ($svr in $getSvrs) {
    try {
        $winRMServiceStatus= (Get-Service -ComputerName $svr -Name WinRM -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Status
        $serverReachable = $true
        $found = $svr
        break;
    }
    catch {
        $serverReachable = $false
    }
}

if($serverReachable) {"found $found with WinRM status $winRMServiceStatus"} else{"No server responded"}
```

In your example, you are trying to access $srv outside of the foreach loop where it is not available.

I was able to quick test it in my lab, let me know how it works for you.